# Product with Multiple Variations

Tags: django, database, postgresql, hstore

I am going through with the process of building an eCommerce website. I am working with Django and Postgresql for Product storage.

I have come up with the Product Multiple variations problem. Specially working with different kind of product where products of different types could have different options. And the variation is a product combined by multiple options.

I have gone through the analysis and finally came up with 2 solutions that could solve it for me.

The first is creating multiple tables related to each other:

Products

Variations | Belongs-to:Product

Options | Belongs-to:Products

Option_Values | Belongs-to:Options

Variation_Option_Values | Belongs-to:Variations| Belongs-to:Options }| Belongs-to: Option_Values

Now, Lately i've stumbled around HStore() for Postgresql which allows data to be stored as Key:Value into the field of a table. Where i can store the options and its values in the same table.

It would reduce the tables amount and makes it easier to implement.

Any ideas on which method would be better as in terms of querying speed and efficiency. Along with any design suggestions ?

Comment: You need to think about what sort of queries you will be doing. Using tables will give you freedom to run complex queries and have consistent properties across products. If you would rather have more freedom in what sort of properties a product could have without needing to query or group products by properties much then key-value or even json field could be better.

Comment: Thanks for  your response. Currently the operations i could think of are simple. The only part that concerns me is searching for for the values. Such as a Color, a Size, Capacity in case of smart phones or even parts in case of a Bicycle. Would it be very complex to issue those queries ? I have read the documentation on Django website and the process to query seems similar to the way we query normal tables. but no mention on the performance. one more thing would be the process of adding an API to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Querying Hstore is slower than querying traditional relational scheme, but is comparable to other NoSQL databases.

Problem will be if you want to update the Hstore frequently. It consumes a lot of memory, cause the whole dictionary gets unloaded-changed-and saved back to database(postgres guys are improving on this). It would be senseless to use Hstore if data is large and needs frequent changes. While just searching through it won't be a performance problem. However if you can store it traditionally then opt for it.

If you find Hstore still useful for your case, look into django-hstore. It can help you store data in NoSQL fashion (via SCHEME feature).